# Evaluating `IO` Actions from REPL

Tags: idris

Given:

```
*lecture2> :let x = (the (IO Int) (pure 42))
```

Looking at its type, what's the meaning of the `MkFFI C_Types String String` signature?

```
*lecture2> :t x
x : IO' (MkFFI C_Types String String) Int
```

I then attempted to evaluate `x` from the REPL:

```
*lecture2> :exec x
main:When checking argument value to function Prelude.Basics.the:
        Type mismatch between
                IO Int (Type of x)
        and
                Integer (Expected type)
```

Also, why doesn't `42` print out in the REPL?

Answer (score 1):

> Looking at its type, what's the meaning of the `MkFFI C_Types String String` signature?

The [`IO'` type constructor](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/prelude/IO.idr#L35) is parametrised over the FFI that is available within it. It'll be different depending on e.g. the backend you want to target. Here you have access to the C FFI which is [the default one `IO` picks](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/prelude/IO.idr#L199).

You can find out about these things by using `:doc` in the REPL. E.g. `:doc IO'` yields:

```
Data type IO' : (lang : FFI) -> Type -> Type
    The IO type, parameterised over the FFI that is available within it.

Constructors:
    MkIO : (World -> PrimIO (WorldRes a)) -> IO' lang a
```

> Also, why doesn't 42 print out in the REPL?

I don't know how `:exec x` is supposed to work but you can evaluate `x` in an interpreter by using `:x x` instead and that does yield a sensible output:

```
Idris> :x x
MkIO (\w => prim_io_pure 42) : IO' (MkFFI C_Types String String) Int
```